# After reboot, ssh refuses connection

Tags: 14.04, ssh, openssh

I've never touched `sshd_config`, all ports open (22, 80, 443), ssh status says ssh server is running. I had all working before reboot perfect, now it´s all dead and I can't enter site, neither using ssh nor SFTP.

I did already reinstall ssh-server and ssh-client and rebooted the server.

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server && sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Check if am running SSH:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

says Job is already running:

```
ssh - ssh start/running
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Running the client in verbose mode (`ssh -vvv user@yourhost`) might be a good place to start

Comment: I have had an ssh server get reset to default config durring server update. actualy, your command will "purge" the config file so yeah, that behaviour makes sense.  why are you ssh-ing on 80 and 443? infact, get rid of all those and use port forwarding to a less targeted port. 
try logging in with a command. ssh -p 22 <user>@host tell us what that says. You may need to dump your knownhosts file

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right `port`? `Connection refused` is normally given when the server is not listening on that port.

Comment: Pls refer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543323/ssh-connection-refused-after-reboot